# When the column values for UID and GID fields in /proc/<pid>/status file will differ

Tags: linux, process, procfs

Here is the output of a sample **/proc/pid/status** file.

From the **procfs(5)** Man page, found that those are *Real, Effective, Saved and FileSystem UIDs*

```
Uid:    998     998     998     998
Gid:    996     996     996     996
```

Here all are showing same values.

So, in any chance those four columns will show different UIDs.
Especially among Real, Effective and Filesystem UIDs.

Comment: You say in your own question that these are the Real, Effective, Saved and FileSystem UIDs. You've only got a question in your title, not the actual question, but you'll have to look at OS-specific references fro that, this doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Comment: @ThomasJager Thanks for pointing the correction needed. I just rephrased the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking this as a question:

> So, in any chance those four columns will show different UIDs.

Yes. Subject to various limitations, processes can change their effective and saved UIDs and GIDs.  This is what the `setuid()`, `setgid()`, `seteuid()`, and `setegid()` functions do.

The filesystem uid and gid are Linux-specific features that are used mainly, if not entirely, in the context of NFS (see [filesystem uid and gid in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45863/289373)).  These can be manipulated with `setfsuid()` and `setfsgid()`, subject, again, to limitations.

For most processes, all the UIDs will the same and all the GIDs will be the same, but it is conceivable that they would all be different.  It is a function of the behavior of the process.